# Override Spark application resource demands

Tags: apache-spark

I am currently in the process of setting up a Spark cluster that will be used by several groups of customers, and I am a bit confused regarding to the method of resource allocation in Spark.

It seems that the governance model of the Spark cluster is somewhat lacking, since each application can specify its own resource requirements, effectively consuming the entire cluster and blocking other applications.

I know that I can use spark.deploy.defaultcores to eliminate cases of applications that accidentally end up requesting all available cores, but that still leaves the scenario where an application has specified spark.cores.max that is much higher than what it should actually get. This is a real issue in a shared cluster...

Is there any method from overriding the resource requirements specified by an individual application?

Answer (score 2):

Spark in a shared cluster will not create any problem ,as mostly you would be running Spark application on top of a resource manager like Yarn or Mesos .

Yarn/Mesos both are very good in terms of resource management, you can create your own queue in yarn for different groups. You can select the scheduler algorithm for the queues you create for scheduling jobs of multiple users.

Apart from that you can enable the dynamic resource allocation in spark which will allow run time resource allocation/de-allocation as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. We are currently using standalone mode since we didn't want to extend the stack more than we need to (the cluster is going to be dedicated to Spark), so I was hoping there is some way to achieve this with Spark itself.

Do Yarn/Mesos allow different resource allocation only per user, or is there further granularity? For example, is it possible to submit a spark job in Yarn/Mesos to different resource "queues" using the same account?